# How do I use exceltex on windows

Tags: exceltex

I want to use [exceltex](https://ctan.org/pkg/exceltex) package on windows (MikTeX 2.9 distribution with TeXmaker editor) but I don't understand what procedure is. In [README](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exceltex) file mentioned

> now, run latex, then exceltex and latex again.

which I don't understand this part:

> run exceltex

Comment: Welcome to TeX S.E! AFAIU, this means that from the console or your editor, you have to run `exceltex doc.tex` (where doc.tex is your document name). If you run latex from your editor, you have to create in your menu a new compilation entry for exceltex: copy the formula used to run `latex` and write `exceltex` instead.